# Assembler STRB instructions armv7

Tags: arm, armv7, patch, disassembly, ida

I have this code:

```
STRB            R2, [R0,R1]
```

and its opcode is `42 54`

I'm using this table http://imrannazar.com/ARM-Opcode-Map

but I so 54 is the opcode of my strb istructions.

What I want is `STRB            R2, 1`

I need to assign to R2 register the decimal value 1.

I can't understand wich opcode for STRB I need to use to do what I want.

help me please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To assign a small immediate to a register, just do:

```
mov r2, #1
```

`strb` is used to store to memory.  You're trying to put a value into a register.